# Как вместо вывода Alert открыть страницу по ссылке?

Tags: javascript

```
$('#sendmail').click(function(e){ 
 var formdata = $("#form-sendmail").serialize();   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata+"&id="+tid+"&size="+size,
        url: "/handlers/mailrassilka.php",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          if(data == "true"){  
           alert("ОТКРЫТЬ НОВУЮ СТРАНИЦУ");
           location.reload();
          }else{ alert(data); } 
        }
    });
  e.preventDefault();   
});
```

Comment: `window.open(url)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sendmail').click(function(e){ 
 var formdata = $("#form-sendmail").serialize();   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata+"&id="+tid+"&size="+size,
        url: "/handlers/mailrassilka.php",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          if(data == "true"){
          location = "http://mysite.com"
          }else{ alert(data); } 
        }
    });
  e.preventDefault();   
});
```

Comment: постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы